# How can I add something to an array and move everything down?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to add a score to an array and check if that score is higher than the rest, and put it in the correct position and move everything else down. I have a 2-dimensional array `highScores(9, 1)`, where the first part is each score, and the second part is the name when 0 and the score when 1. I want to be able to check where the new score should be entered and then move everything down if need be.

This is what I have so far, and it doesn't work.

```
Sub AddScore(name As String, score As String)

    For i = 9 To 0 Step -1

        If score > highScores(i, 1) Then

            For j = i To 1 Step -1

                highScores(j - 1, 0) = highScores(j, 0)
                highScores(j - 1, 1) = highScores(j, 1)

            Next

            highScores(i, 0) = name
            highScores(i, 1) = score

            Exit For

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What will happen if you want to move an item down to index -1?

Comment: What will happen when one score is `"90"` and another is `"1685"`? Classes, collections and Linq make this sort of thing simple. Please read [ask] and take the [TOUR]

Comment: I want to check where the new score should be, and then move everything down out of the way so that I can put the new score in the right place.

Comment: Homework questions are allowed here, but you have to do your due diligence first.  Dumping the code and stating "it doesn't work." is insufficient and (hopefully) no one will do your work for you.  Write the steps down on paper of how you would do this manually with a 10 bin rack.  Then translate those steps into code.  If you then have a problem, show us every thing you have including your written down steps with a description of what you can not figure out.

Comment: If all you can say is `it doesn't work` you need to use the debugger at your fingertips, figure out *why* it doesnt work.  Then, if you need help you will be able to give a proper problem description (assuming that you cannot fix it yourself).  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the score at element 9 is the highest score and the score at element 0 is the lowest.

You were close, but not quite there. For a start, you should never do mathematical comparisons on strings. You should convert the strings to numeric values. For this there are several ways, but for you the simplest is to use the `Val` function.

Next. Have a think about what you're trying to achieve. Iterate through the scores from lowest to highest checking the score to see if it is higher than any in the array. If it is, move each high score down to the next element. A key thing here is to remember that element 0 has nowhere to go, it just gets overwritten by the one above. So start going along the array from element 1 to element `i` where you will be placing the new score. For example element 1 overwrites element 0, element 2 overwrites element 1 and so on. When this is done, you simply overwrite element `i` with the new values.

Finally, rather than use `Exit For`, use `Exit Sub` to leave that sub entirely. `Exit For` will only leave the inner `For..Next` loop and will then try to continue the outer loop.

```
Private Sub AddScore(name As String, score As String)
    For i As Integer = 9 To 0 Step -1
        If Val(score) > Val(highScores(i, 1)) Then
            For j As Integer = 1 To i 
                highScores(j - 1, 0) = highScores(j, 0)
                highScores(j - 1, 1) = highScores(j, 1)
            Next
            highScores(i, 0) = name
            highScores(i, 1) = score
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```